# pop up dialog comes twice on double click of edit text

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

actually i am displaying a pop up with ok cancel button when user clicks on edit text.
My problem is when ever user double clicks on edit text two pop up comes. so if user has selected any value from pop up its second pop up still remain there.

I don't know how to deal with it.

Any help will appreciated. thanks in advance. 
This is my layout

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/date_control"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:background="@drawable/bg_edit_text"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
      android:inputType="none"
      android:editable="false"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

My java class calling the controller

```
datePicker = (EditText) findView(R.id.date_control);
datePicker.setOnClickListener(myControllerClass);
```

its controller

```
MyDialog myDialog = new myDialog(activity, "Select Date", 
                    date, DateTimeDialog.DATE_PICKER);
myDialog.show();
```

Comment: Don't know if you should ever bother about such a problem, cause double clicking isn't used in Android at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you keep a field reference to your dialog you could check to see if its already showing

```
if(myDialog == null) {
    myDialog = new myDialog(activity, "Select Date", 
                    date, DateTimeDialog.DATE_PICKER);
}

if(!myDialog.isShowing()) {
    myDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your edittext clickable false after click (means your dialog gets display) then on dialog dismiss you can again make your edittext clickable true.

you have to set this property programmatically .. for EditText properties [link..](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

Hope this explanation works for you..

Comment: I don't know why but its not working. any ways thanks for answer. Ian answer worked for me